# Filling a 2D Array with Another Array

Tags: python, arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I am trying to fill a 2D array using a for loop, with a variable that is an array. From this array, I am hoping to find the average of each column and input this into a new array.

However, I don't know how to input the variable into a 2D array.

```
A_values = numpy.zeros([20, 1])

print(A_values)

for i in range(0,20):
    A_values([1,i]) = xa
```

In this code, xa is a variable that changes with each iteration and has a length of 402.

I am trying to get it so that the 2d array 'A_values' has 402 columns and 20 rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you necessarily looking to use for-loops? I am asking because this problem can be solved in simpler and more efficient ways such as:

```py
import numpy as np

a_values = np.random.rand(20,402) #Store random values in a_values with a shape of 20 rows and 402 columns
avg_columns = a_values.mean(axis=0) #Calculate the mean of each column 

print(avg_columns)
```

Documentation for generating random values: [numpy.random.rand](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.random.rand.html)

EDIT:

I assumed that xa is randomized in each iteration (make sure to replace it with the `xa` that you are generating). You can initialize an empty `a_values` array, and add the generated `xa` array to it in each iteration using `np.vstack`. For the first iteration, when `a_value` is empty, I made it equal to `xa` (`if a_values.size else xa`).

```py
import numpy as np

a_values = np.array([])

for i in range(20):
  xa = np.random.rand(1,402)
  a_values = np.vstack([a_values, xa]) if a_values.size else xa

avg_columns = a_values.mean(axis=0) #Average of each column
```

Documentation for vstack: [numpy.vstack](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.vstack.html)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearers the array isn't filled with random numbers it is filled with integers representing the number of A particles left in a radioactive decay process. Thank you though!

Comment: No problem. I edited my post, is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, thank you again! the problem in my code turned out to be using brackets around square brackets continuing to give me a call function error. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can change the shape of **A_values** after it's defined. So you should start with:

```
A_values = numpy.zeros([20,402])
```

And if your for loop is iterating through the **rows**, your index should be **[i, 1]** (numpy array indexes are not like cartesian plane coords).

But you want to change entire rows of A_values, to do this you use just the first index:

```
A_values[row] = some_row
```

Remember that "some_row" needs to have the proper lenght, otherwise you get a ValueError.

Your final code will look like this:

```
A_values = numpy.zeros([20, 402])

for i in range(0,20):
    A_values([i]) = xa
```

PS: You should describe the errors you are getting and be clearer if you want help with the "xa" values as well...

Comment: thank you for your help! However, I am getting an error which reads "can't assign to function call" .   xa = numpy.concatenate([evolve_system(NA, NB, NC, rules1, nsteps)[0], evolve_system(final_NA, final_NB, final_NC, rules2, nsteps)[0]]), where evolve_system is a function previously defined.

Comment: What does evolve_system returns? To use numpy.concatenate(), both arguments must be numpy.arrays and you need to use the right axis. Have a look here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html
(i actually think the error is in the evolve_system function now)

Comment: evolve_systems returns an array of integers.

Comment: you should remove this outer pair of square brackets:
numpy.concatenate(evolve_system(NA, NB, NC, rules1, nsteps)[0], evolve_system(final_NA, final_NB, final_NC, rules2, nsteps)[0])